# How to verify a gpg-signed file against a specific public key?

Tags: gnupg, digital-signature, public-key

**Background information:** I have a directory full of files and detached `.asc` signatures. I also have my default keyring which includes many public keys of people (some of whom I trust and others I don't).

If I verify all files in the directory, gpg outputs something similar to the following for *each* file:

```
Signature made XXX using RSA key ID XXXX
Good signature from SIGNER
```

My issue stems from needing to check these lines for each file to make sure that the signer is who I expect it to be. What I would like to do is limit which public key gpg can use to verify files.

**Question:** Is it possible to configure gpg to only use one public key to verify files?

One solution is to use a new temporary keyring (with only one key) every time I needed to verify files. But this solution quicky becomes tedious if I need to do it more than a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the information provided via "status-fd":

```
$ cat message.txt | gpg --verify --status-fd=1
[GNUPG:] NEWSIG
gpg: Signature made 2019-12-18T15:06:03 EET
gpg:                using RSA key 2357E10CEF...
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 2357Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2632 0
[GNUPG:] SIG_ID XZf34rp0ZuF0AqxbAkJhqrEV/Og 2019-12-18 1576674363
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 2357Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2632 0
[GNUPG:] GOODSIG xxxxxxxxxxxx2632 Fred Foobar <fred@example.com>
gpg: Good signature from "Fred Foobar <fred@example.com>" [ultimate]
[GNUPG:] VALIDSIG 2357Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2632 2019-12-18 1576674363 0 4 0 1 10 00 2357Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2632
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 2357Exxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2632 0
[GNUPG:] TRUST_ULTIMATE 0 pgp
[GNUPG:] VERIFICATION_COMPLIANCE_MODE 23
```

So if you wanted to ensure that it's signed by a specific key, you would use:

```
verify_with() {
    local fingerprint=$1
    local file=$2
    local status

    fingerprint=$(echo "$fingerprint" | tr a-z A-Z | tr -dc A-Z)

    status=$(gpg --status-fd=4 --trust-model=always verify "$file" 4>&1 >/dev/null 2>&1)

    if grep -qs "^\\[GNUPG:\\] VALIDSIG $fingerprint " <<< "$status"; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}
```